# mysql query to count from related tables twice

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem getting my query the way I want it.  I have 2 tables:
Passages and Questions tables

The questions table has a foreign key of a Passage.  The questions table has a column named status that is either active, inactive, or review.  I was able to get the count of active questions but now I want to get the count of questions in review also but I cant seem to get it correct. The following is what I came up with so far but the questionsinreview column just gives me the same number as numquestions.

```
SELECT 
p."id",  
COUNT(q."PassageId") as numQuestions, 
COUNT(q2."PassageId") AS questionsInReview, 
ROUND(AVG(q."level")) as "questionLevel" 
FROM 
"Passages" as p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Questions" as q ON p.id=q."PassageId" AND q."status" = 'active'
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Questions" as q2 on p.id=q2."PassageId" where q2."status" = 'review'
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

How should I set up my query to be able to get the count of questions in review also?

EDIT:

After playing around with what was suggested here is what I got to work

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT 
   p.id, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN q."status" = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numQuestions, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN q."status" = 'review' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS questionsInReview, 
   ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN q."status" = 'active' THEN q."level" ELSE Null END)) as questionLevel
FROM "Passages" AS p 
LEFT JOIN "Questions" as q ON p.id = q."PassageId"
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like (untested):

```
SELECT p.id,  
       COUNT(q.id) AS numQuestions, 
       SUM(q.status = "review") AS questionsInReview, 
       ROUND(AVG(if(q.status = "active", q.level, null)) as questionLevel
FROM Passages AS p 
LEFT JOIN Questions as q ON p.id = q.PassageId AND q.status = 'active'
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Comment: This worked for me the best as it was the simplest solution.  Edited the question to have the solution.  Had to tweak this query a little to make it work

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your answer is that you are just counting rows- since you are joining, the number of rows is the same.

Try this approach:

```
SELECT id, sum(active) as sum_active, sum(review) as sum_review from (
  SELECT p.id, 
    CASE q.status WHEN 'active' 1 ELSE 0 AS active,
    CASE q.status WHEN 'review' 1 ELSE 0 AS review
  FROM Passages as p inner join Questions as q ON p.id = q.passageId
) group by id
```

The idea- the inner query will just give you binary columns for active and review. this way you can simply sum them up to get the result